# What is the best Head Cascade Classifier in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian, opencv3.1

I am using OpenCV 3.1 on a Raspbian Jessie OS using pi zero board.

I used "haarcascade_frontalface_alt" for face detection and it works really good on low resolution images using Python. What i want to do is to detect the heads of people since i may not have their faces in the captured images.

What is the best cascade to use in this case? also is there a catalog page that describe existing cascades and the use case for each one?

Thanks.

Comment: all the face detection classifiers will need the faces. There exist other detectors to detect shape of head+shoulders but afaik they only provide matlab code, not C++/python/openCV

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at all the haarcascade files of opencv by listing the contents of `data/haarcascades/` in you `opencv` folder. The names of the xml files are pretty self explanatory.

This website http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34/ contains other cascades files and particularly a file for "head and shoulders" that could be appropriate for you.

Comment: Thanks @fonfonx i looked at this site already but what they have is not what i am looking for. I tried their Head cascade xml file but did not provide any detection for heads from the top.